# chrome.app.window.create Incognito Window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app, and was wondering how to create a fullscreen Incognito window.

```
function openWindow(path){
  chrome.system.display.getInfo(function(d){
    chrome.app.window.create(path, {
      'frame': 'none',
      'id': 'browser',
      'bounds':{
         'left':0,
         'top':0,
         'width':d[0].bounds.width,
         'height':d[0].bounds.height
       }
    },function(w){
      w.fullscreen();
    });
  });
}
```

This creates a regular window. Adding

```
'incognito': true,
```

didn't work.

Comment: I'd imagine ending in a semi-colon ";" would break the object. Try add it `'incognito': true,`

Comment: There is no such concept as "incognito app window". And app window is not a regular Chrome browsing window. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, `'incognito': true,` is what I tried. Typo.

Comment: I'm trying to make a kiosk browser that has zero caching, history, etc.

Comment: So you are using a webview inside the app?

Comment: Yes. I suppose I didn't understand conceptually what was happening on window.create. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "browser" inside the [`<webview>` tag](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) is stateful, but the state is not persistent unless you specify a [partition attribute](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition).

If you don't specify a partition, the state (cookies, localStorage, etc.) is lost when the element is destroyed, e.g. on an app window restart. It does, however, survive as long as the `<webview>` element lives.

Furthermore, at any point you can wipe any part of the state as you would do with Chrome, via [`<webview>.clearData()` function](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-clearData). In a public kiosk mode, it's probably a good idea to do this if the app was inactive for a period or the user explicitly indicates he finished browsing.

Answer (score 1):

To echo one of Xan's comments above, Chrome App windows are not browser windows. As they have no cookies or history of any kind, they are inherently incognito. Caching is for performance, so the HTML processor probably does caching, but I would think that caching isn't much of a privacy issue.

Comment: This is not entirely true; see my answer.

Comment: At the same time, Marc's comment is valuable because it emphasizes the single point that the concept of incognito doesn't apply to things that aren't Chrome browser tabs, such as Chrome App windows.